# Wordpress title positioning with CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm converting someone's static HTML design to Wordpress, but I run into a problem when working with the titles.

The case is that the title expands downwards, which means that when one title becomes more than one line, the other titles also jump up, even though they are only one line.

This is what happens
[image: This is what happens]

This is how I want it
[image]

This is the CSS I use to position the titles so the bottom of the title hits the bottom of the image:

```
.single_title {
    font-family:Novecent_norm, arial, helvetica, sans serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 240px;
    color: white;
    background-color: purple;
    margin-top: -86px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

So the question is: Is there a CSS property that can solve this problem, so extra lines of text get added on TOP of the title instead at the BOTTOM of it?

As requested, the HTML:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="content_container">
    <div class="thumb_art">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
            <div class="thumb_img" style="z-index: 0;">
            <?php
            if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                the_post_thumbnail();
            }?>
            </div>
            </a></h2>

        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
        <div class="single_title">

                <?php the_title();?>

            </div></a></h2>
    </div>
</div>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="navigation">  <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Next Entries') ?></div>  <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('Previous Entries &raquo;') ?></div></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you paste a full example of the HTML too?

Comment: As requested I added the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make thumb_art position relative and then set bottom to 0 on single_title to get it always stick to the bottom

**css**

```
.single_title {
    font-family:Novecent_norm, arial, helvetica, sans serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 240px;
    color: white;
    background-color: purple;
    bottom:0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

*And if not already set to relative add this aswell*

```
.thumb_art{
   position:relative;//actually any positioning would do
}
```

Still not entirely sure if I understood your question correctly, if there is something im missing please do tell.

**Edit:**

This is how it would look like if you had used my method

http://jsfiddle.net/nhewu/

Comment: This dumps the titles completely to the bottom of the page: http://oi35.tinypic.com/2vc9e8g.jpg

My question was if there is a way to let text shift upwards when there is a line break, instead of going to a new line. Hopefully my crappy GIF explains it a bit, haha! http://oi36.tinypic.com/5cy355.jpg

So I want old lines to move up, while the new line stays on the same line. I guess it's not possible, otherwise I would've found it already. Might just go with a max. amount of chars and end it with ... if more chars.

Comment: @Rvervuurt there is no true linebreakin upwards, what you have to do is force the container grow upwards to simulate your desired result.
Does it have to be fixed im sure it will work if you change position to absolute on `.single_title` or if i could get a link to the site I could take a quicker look and find you a solution

Comment: I went for the ... solution, because that also looks better than having titles that sometimes are one line, sometimes four lines etc. The width is only 240px, so it would get really messy with titles.
The position absolute didn't fix it, that's what I started with. It would let them stick to the bottom, but didn't fix that linebreak upwards thing. So, both code-wise and design-wise I decided to go with cutting the title. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: I accepted your answer because apparently you got it working. Thanks again!